# Can anyone see the flaw in my code?

Tags: python

couple issues with my code I need help working out.

1. how do I get the header to only print once above the results, and not at all if nothing meetings the criteria?
2. the else component of my code is no longer working, it used to just print if none of the other scenarios were true but I updated it and now it keeps printing every time. Can anyone spot the issue?

Code:

```
import Hotels

htl_1= Hotels.Hotels(111,100,1,1)
htl_2= Hotels.Hotels(112,200,2,1)
htl_3= Hotels.Hotels(113,250,2,2)
htl_4= Hotels.Hotels(114,300,3,2)
htl_5= Hotels.Hotels(115,350,3,3)


feeInput=input('Enter maximum per night fee: ')
roomInput=input('Enter minimum number of bedrooms: ')
bathInput=input('Enter minimum number of baths: ')


header='{:10} {:10} {:10} {:10}'.format('Room#','Cost','Rooms','Bathrooms')

print(header)

if int(feeInput)>= htl_1.fee and int(roomInput)<= htl_1.rooms and int(bathInput)<= htl_1.bath:
    print(htl_1.gethtl())
if int(feeInput)>= htl_2.fee and int(roomInput)<= htl_2.rooms and int(bathInput)<= htl_2.bath:
    print(htl_2.gethtl())
if int(feeInput)>= htl_3.fee and int(roomInput)<= htl_3.rooms and int(bathInput)<= htl_3.bath:
    print(htl_3.gethtl())
if int(feeInput)>= htl_4.fee and int(roomInput)<= htl_4.rooms and int(bathInput)<= htl_4.bath:
    print(htl_4.gethtl())
if int(feeInput)>= htl_5.fee and int(roomInput)<= htl_5.rooms and int(bathInput)<= htl_5.bath:
    print(htl_5.gethtl())

else:
    print('Sorry, no rooms available that meet that criteria')
```

Comment: You need to fix the formatting.

Comment: sorry I keep highlighting it and doing the brackets {} but its not working!

Comment: You need a line after the numbers in Markdown.

Comment: Give a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in your question.

Comment: and please ... put the `int(feeInput)` where it belongs (and cosider using errorhandling). The correct place would be here: `feeInput=int(input('Enter maximum per night fee: '))`  & the same for the other 2 numeric inputs  - not on every conditional statement!

Comment: Thank you for the help, i did it a different way and got it working better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the Hotels module I believe this syntax is correct. In order for the else to only activate when none of those if statements are true, you need to change them to elif (after the first if statement) as shown. The .format you used only works inside of a print statment as shown. Thanks

```
import Hotels

htl_1= Hotels.Hotels(111,100,1,1)
htl_2= Hotels.Hotels(112,200,2,1)
htl_3= Hotels.Hotels(113,250,2,2) 
htl_4= Hotels.Hotels(114,300,3,2)
htl_5= Hotels.Hotels(115,350,3,3)

feeInput = int(input('Enter maximum per night fee: '))
roomInput = int(input('Enter minimum number of bedrooms: '))
bathInput = int(input('Enter minimum number of baths: '))

header = True

if feeInput >= htl_1.fee and roomInput <= htl_1.rooms and bathInput<= htl_1.bath: 
    print(htl_1.gethtl())
elif feeInput >= htl_2.fee and roomInput <= htl_2.rooms and bathInput <= htl_2.bath: 
    print(htl_2.gethtl()) 
elif feeInput >= htl_3.fee and roomInput <= htl_3.rooms and bathInput <= htl_3.bath: 
    print(htl_3.gethtl()) 
elif feeInput >= htl_4.fee and roomInput <= htl_4.rooms and bathInput <= htl_4.bath: 
    print(htl_4.gethtl()) 
elif feeInput >= htl_5.fee and roomInput <= htl_5.rooms and bathInput <= htl_5.bath: 
    print(htl_5.gethtl())
else: 
    print('Sorry, no rooms available that meet that criteria')
    header = False

if header == True:
    print('{0} {1} {2} {3}'.format(RoomVar,CostVar,RoomsVar,BathroomsVar))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `if` to `elif` and move the header printing code to `if` blocks as well.